# Как создать передвигающийся блок?

Tags: виджет, qt, c++

Всем привет.
Как отобразить блок на форме?
Блок содержит текстовое поле(входной параметр), т.е. внутри блока есть текстовое поле.

[image: Пример обычной формы]

Внутри него должен быть блок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

использовать текстовое поле и обрамить его рамкой

Comment: как сделать так чтобы оно двигалось при выделении внутри формы после запуска?

Comment: менять его координаты (в свойствах) в зависимости от положения курсора и нажатой кнопке мыши

Comment: есть пример?)

Comment: нет---------